# Match query with multiple values

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a list of values and I want all documents that have any of these values in their `product_code` field.

I tried this, but even though it doesn't give an error, it only gives me one of the documents:

```
"query": {
  "match": {
    "product_code": {
      "query": ["ABC 4", "ABC 5"]
    }
  }
}
```

So I'm basically looking for the functionality of the `terms` filter, but with analysis.

Of course I could do:

```
"bool": {
  "should": [
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "product_code": "ABC 4"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "product_code": "ABC 5"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but this gets rather verbose for long lists.

`product_code` is defined like this:

```
"product_code": {
  "type": "string",
  "analyzer": "product_code",
}
```

with the *product_code* analyzer:

```
"product_code": {
  "type": "custom",
  "filter": [
    "lowercase",
    "trim"
  ],
  "tokenizer": "keyword"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent of the `terms` query for `match` AFAIK. Another option is the `query_string` which is less verbose:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "product_code",
      "query": "\"ABC 4\" OR \"ABC 5\""
    }
  }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: This looks good... are there any special characters I have to escape inside the quotes besides other quotes? Or just put no quotes but escape everything special including the space?

Comment: You'll need to escape the special characters that Lucene lists here:http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping Special Characters

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but how about:

```
{
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { "product_code" : ["ABC 4", "ABC 5"]}
        }
    }
}
```

Could this be what you're looking for?

Comment: Does it analyze the terms?

Comment: The `terms` query doesn't analyze terms.